# Are there any openCL test suites?

Tags: parallelization, gpu

I have a new ATI gpu that I have been trying on 3 different distributed computing projects.  I get errors on each work unit.

The errors indicate *No Protocol* which could be caused by a bad environment variable that doesn't point to the correct path.

On Linux, Mathematica returns $Failed for this:

```
Environment["ATISTREAMSDKROOT"]
```

So, I was wondering if there is a test suite that would validate the calculations of such a card?

```
{1->{Version->OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (923.1),Name->AMD Accelerated Parallel   Processing,Vendor->Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.,Extensions->{cl_khr_icd,cl_amd_event_callback,cl_amd_offline_devices},1->{Type->GPU,Name->Cypress,Version->OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (923.1),Extensions->{cl_khr_fp64,cl_amd_fp64,cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics,cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics,cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics,cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics,cl_khr_3d_image_writes,cl_khr_byte_addressable_store,cl_khr_gl_sharing,cl_ext_atomic_counters_32,cl_amd_device_attribute_query,cl_amd_vec3,cl_amd_printf,cl_amd_media_ops,cl_amd_popcnt},Driver Version->CAL 1.4.1741,Vendor->Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.,Profile->FULL_PROFILE,Vendor ID->4098,Compute Units->18,Core Count->1440,Maximum Work Item Dimensions->3,Maximum Work Item Sizes->{256,256,256},Maximum Work Group Size->256,Preferred Vector Width Character->16,Preferred Vector Width Short->16,Preferred Vector Width Integer->4,Preferred Vector Width Long->2,Preferred Vector Width Float->4,Preferred Vector Width Double->2,Maximum Clock Frequency->765,Address Bits->32,Maximum Memory Allocation Size->134217728,Image Support->True,Maximum Read Image Arguments->128,Maximum Write Image Arguments->8,Maximum Image2D Width->8192,Maximum Image2D Height->8192,Maximum Image3D Width->2048,Maximum Image3D Height->2048,Maximum Image3D Depth->2048,Maximum Samplers->16,Maximum Parameter Size->1024,Memory Base Address Align->2048,Memory Data Type Align Size->128,Floating Point Precision Configuration->{Infinity,NaNs,Round to Nearest,Round to Infinity,Round to Zero,IEEE754-2008 Fused MAD},Global Memory Cache Type->None,Global Memory Cache Line Size->0,Global Memory Cache Size->0,Global Memory Size->536870912,Maximum Constant Buffer Size->65536,Maximum Constant Arguments->8,Local Memory Type->Local,Local Memory Size->32768,Error Correction Support->False,Profiling Timer Resolution->1,Endian Little->True,Available->True,Compiler Available->True,Execution Capabilities->{Kernel Execution},Command Queue Properties->Profiling Enabled},2->{Type->CPU,Name->AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor,Version->OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (923.1),Extensions->{cl_khr_fp64,cl_amd_fp64,cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics,cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics,cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics,cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics,cl_khr_int64_base_atomics,cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics,cl_khr_byte_addressable_store,cl_khr_gl_sharing,cl_ext_device_fission,cl_amd_device_attribute_query,cl_amd_vec3,cl_amd_printf,cl_amd_media_ops,cl_amd_popcnt},Driver Version->2.0 (sse2),Vendor->AuthenticAMD,Profile->FULL_PROFILE,Vendor ID->4098,Compute Units->6,Core Count->6,Maximum Work Item Dimensions->3,Maximum Work Item Sizes->{1024,1024,1024},Maximum Work Group Size->1024,Preferred Vector Width Character->16,Preferred Vector Width Short->16,Preferred Vector Width Integer->4,Preferred Vector Width Long->2,Preferred Vector Width Float->4,Preferred Vector Width Double->0,Maximum Clock Frequency->3314,Address Bits->64,Maximum Memory Allocation Size->4215913470,Image Support->True,Maximum Read Image Arguments->128,Maximum Write Image Arguments->8,Maximum Image2D Width->8192,Maximum Image2D Height->8192,Maximum Image3D Width->2048,Maximum Image3D Height->2048,Maximum Image3D Depth->2048,Maximum Samplers->16,Maximum Parameter Size->4096,Memory Base Address Align->1024,Memory Data Type Align Size->128,Floating Point Precision Configuration->{Denorms,Infinity,NaNs,Round to Nearest,Round to Infinity,Round to Zero,IEEE754-2008 Fused MAD},Global Memory Cache Type->Read Write,Global Memory Cache Line Size->64,Global Memory Cache Size->65536,Global Memory Size->16863653880,Maximum Constant Buffer Size->65536,Maximum Constant Arguments->8,Local Memory Type->Global,Local Memory Size->32768,Error Correction Support->False,Profiling Timer Resolution->1,Endian Little->True,Available->True,Compiler Available->True,Execution Capabilities->{Kernel Execution,Native Kernel Execution},Command Queue Properties->Profiling Enabled}}}
```

EDIT: when I run an example I get: OpenCLMemoryAllocate::invdev: OpenCLLink device is invalid.

Since the information in the scroll-bar above seems to be complete, I don't have any idea what to fix.

**Coda**  I solved this by running as root.  It seems the AMD Linux driver has a slight permissions problem accessing the libaries.

Comment: Please repost your code as text. It will have syntax highlighting, and its own scrollbox so that the total post will be shorter.

Comment: What is your definiton of "validation"?

Comment: What kinds of errors did you get for what code that you tried? Did you try the OpenCL examples in the documentation?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, edited OP to show errors.  I believe it has to do with a bad path.  But I'm more interested in some kind of shakedown test to look for possible surprises.

Comment: @YvesKlett, I figured there might be something that would compare calculations on the gpu with calculations on the cpu to test precision, etc.

Comment: But Fred, what was the code that got you that error? Was that example code? Do you have a link or is it small enough to post here?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, there is no Mathematica code.  I bomb off on binaries distributed by POEM@Home, MilkyWay@Home, and PrimeGrid@Home.

Comment: For starters, could you try the code on this MMA doc page: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/tutorial/Introduction.html  Does it run?

Comment: I had a look at *Mathematica*'s OpenCL detection code a while ago and it struck me that it works more through luck than judgment in some cases. `ATISTREAMSDKROOT` is definitely wrong, however--try `AMDAPPSDKROOT` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This is only for CUDA, I did not pay proper attention there (feel free to comment on deletion). Doing the same with OpenCL would be considerably more work.

Do you mean something like this? This compares the results for equivalent `Map` and `CUDAMap` expressions:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]

vals = Table[i, {i, 0, 10, .1}];    
m1 = CUDAMap[Cos, vals];    
m2 = Map[Cos, vals];

m1 == m2
```

> True

`CUDAMap` even balks at invalid operations:

```
CUDAMap[Erf, vals];
```

> CUDAMap::op: Specified operation, Erf, is invalid. Valid operations are: Cos, Sin, Tan, ArcCos, ArcSin, ArcTan, Cosh, Sinh, Exp, Log, Log10, Sqrt, Ceiling, Floor, Abs >>

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I want, only for openCL.  And I want to test the gpu as well as the cpu.

Comment: @FredDanielKline sorry, the convenient versions are only there for CUDA at the moment. But the [OpenCL documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/OpenCLLink/tutorial/Programming.html) should show the way for your own implementation...

Comment: @FredDanielKline thanks for the accept! I am still a bit embarrassed about equating OpenCL with CUDA... if you refine your question (see the comments) I guess more helpful suggestions will be put forward in good time.